# Why doesn't paramater's name conflict with function's name?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I don't understand why in the example below there are no errors taking into account that the name of the function is `tableView` and the first parameter's name is also `tablewView`? Shouldn't they both conflict with each other?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Comment: The parameter name shadows the function name

Comment: Besides, the name of the function is `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`

Comment: @vacawama Could you please tell me why the name is the one you mentioned? I also don't fully understand how the header of this function (and similar ones) works: "cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath" - shouldn't the format be name_of_paramater:Type ? What does cellForRowAtIndexPath stand for? Thanks.